# How to open a relative path image within the IDE

Tags: eclipse

I have a series of status images, and switch that decides which to load

```
icon = "relative/path/image/green.gif";
```

I know I can just go to the file, but I saw someone else do it some time ago and I'd like to know exactly how. I tried to select, right click and all kinds of "open" but none seem to do the trick.

**To try and add some clarity:** select a string to a local file, right click said selection, open within an IDE view / window. I've seen it done, otherwise I'd think it's not possible

Comment: This is very unclear. Are you asking how to do something programmatically? What programming language?

Comment: @greg-449 select a string to a local file, right click said selection, open within an IDE view / window. I've seen it done, otherwise I'd think it's not possible.

Comment: [AnyEdit Tools](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/anyedit-tools) provides the feature _Open File under Cursor_. Is that what you're looking for?